# Demultiplexer 1 to 4 - high specification

Tags: led-driver, power-output-stage

I'm working on a power stage (LED driver) that could manage 4 different LEDs color string. Each string is composed by 6 LEDs in serie.
See the image to have a better idea:

[image]
[image]

The schematic is composed by different components, and I can not consider to make 4 different circuit for each color.

To drive these strings I need at least 20.4 V in output and a maximum current of 30 mA.

Do you know a demultiplexer that has this specification?

- Vcc>21V
- Iout_max >= 30mA

Otherwise, is there another idea to manage 4 different color with only 1 driver?

Thank you very Much

**Edit**:
Thanks Everybody for the feedback.
Here you will find the schematic of the output:[image]

The flag Out+ indicates the output of the driver (the source of a P-mosfet).
Below you will find the forward voltage of a single LED when the current is 20mA:

- Red:   2.1 V
- Green: 3.1 V
- Blue:  3.1 V
- White: 3.15 V

The LEDs are connected by common cathod.

The goal is to add a component between Out+ and the colors, in order to select which string has to be ON.
Please, note that only one string at a time remain ON.

Cheers

**Edit V2**:

I found this high speed analogic switch: DG411
Datasheet: https://www.mouser.ch/datasheet/2/427/dg411hs-1815624.pdf

Could this be a elegant solution?

Comment: Please provide a schematic showing how the LEDs are connected, as well as links to the manufacturer's datasheets for the LEDs.

Comment: There are power shift registers like the TPIC6C595. If you really want a demux, combine a logic device with stronger drivers.

Comment: Please do the schematic, they are a lot more symbols then colors and almost all of us understand them. Frizzy pictures do not count. At this point there are probably a hundred or more answers to your question, please narrow it down with details like voltages and loads.

Comment: Why do you need to connect these things directly to a demultiplexer? Why can't you put a transistor switch on each string and connect the switch gates to a demultiplexer? You are trying to solve this problem the wrong way IMO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to solve this problem the wrong way. You don't need a high-power demultiplexer.

And 21V, 30mA is barely high-power anyway. It's only high-power relative to logic circuits. Anything designed to handle power will have no trouble handling that.

What you do need is a component to turn each string on and off, and then a separate component that demultiplexes. In fact, if you have 4 output pins available, you don't even need the demultiplexer. Just build it like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEhVZP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(please ignore that I didn't delete the automatic numbering from every LED. The LED numbers are irrelevant.)

Use a logic-level MOSFET - pay attention to the gate voltage so that it turns on  properly when the controller outputs a high signal. Some MOSFETs require quite high gate voltages to turn on all the way. Although at only 30mA, maybe it doesn't even matter very much.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your answer @user253751

I will probably do this way, with a little change:

The cathodes of the load are in common, and this can not be changed. So, I will put the mosfet before the string, with this configuration:

[image]

With the Opamp, I'm sure that the voltage turn on the mosfet.